# What are the regional demographics of StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out what resources people in Europe (esp. Denmark) use for finding solutions to SharePoint (or other technology related) issues. Is there a way to identify where StackExchange users are concentrated? Does anyone here live or work in Northern Europe and know of alternative sites?

Comment: I live in Sweden, but I do not really get why you would need local sites to get help / gain knowledge? I know there are some LinkedIn groups with a more local scopes

Comment: I'm planning to move to Denmark with my (Danish) wife and children in November, and I'm hoping to build up a reputation as a trusted SharePoint resource before I get there.

Comment: Ah then I understand what you're aiming at :)

Comment: :) So, do you have any sites (or LinkedIn groups) you can recommend? (Feel free to PM me.)